Android - How to ignore deep links with query parameters
I have an Android app and I want to support "https://www.example.com/" deep links, but I don't want to support "https://www.example.com/?section=footer" deep links.
In other words: if a user with my app installed clicks on a "https://www.example.com/?section=footer" link, the device's browser should open instead of the app, but if he clicks on a "https://www.example.com/" link, the app should open.
Is this possible?
I have the following in my AndroidManifest file:
<intent-filter
    android:autoVerify="true"
    tools:targetApi="m">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="www.example.com" />
    <data android:path="/" />
</intent-filter>

I've tried to detect if the app was opened using a link with the query parameter, and then starting an ACTION_VIEW Intent with the same link, in order for the browser to open.
fun handleIntent(intent: Intent) {
    val uri = intent.data ?: return
    if (!uri.getQueryParameter("section").isNullOrBlank()) {
        val openInBrowserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
        openInBrowserIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}

But this will make the app itself to open again, entering on a loop state and not solving the issue.
